# Никак не могу выровнить текст по центру в чем дело?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

```css
body {
  background-image: url("/Users/kamil/Desktop/ Mebel/изображения /body.jpg");
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.top-menu {
  background: #630000;
  box-shadow: 3px 0 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  padding: 15px;
}

.top-menu:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.navbar-logo {
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu-main {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: right;
}

.menu-main li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu-main a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 61px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-family: 'Arimo', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #EAE2C9;
  transition: .3s linear;
}

.menu-main a:before {
  content: "";
  width: 9px;
  height: 9px;
  background: #EAE2C9;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(6.5px);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .3s linear;
}

.menu-main a:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
}

@media (max-width: 660px) {
  .menu-main {
    float: none;
    padding-top: 20px;
  }
  .top-menu {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 0 0 0;
  }
  .menu-main a {
    padding: 0 10px;
  }
  .menu-main a:before {
    transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(-6px);
  }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .menu-main li {
    display: block;
  }
}

.container {
  background-color: #EAE2C9;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: #000000;
  width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  max-width: 1480px;
  min-height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0, auto;
}

.logoo {
  color: #630000;
  font-family: 'Pattaya', sans-serif;
}


/*.information{
  text-align:center;
  font-size: 2vw;

}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Contrail+One" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pattaya" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- меню в разделе ;контакты;-->
<nav class="top-menu">
  <a class="navbar-logo" href="/Users/kamil/Desktop/ Mebel/index.html"><img src="/Users/kamil/Desktop/ Mebel/изображения /logo.jpg" height="80" width="200"></a>
  <ul class="menu-main">
    <li><a href="">Товары</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Услуги</a></li>
    <li><a href="">О нас</a></li>
    <li><a href="" id="cont">Контакты</a></li>
    <li class="text-center"><a href="8-987-724-1869">tel:8-987-724-186</a></li>
    <li class="text-right"><a href="8-902-100-4887">tel:8-902-100-488</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <div style="text-align:center;">
    <h1>«Студия мебели <span class="logoo">Идеал</span>»</h1>
  </div>
```

Comment: надо вставлять изображения на вэб страницу не от корня диска а от расположения index.html к примеру из папки img/images и так же касается всех файлов касающихся вашего будущего сайта style.css и js файлов и т д для body писать relative не обязательно так как он всё равно relative если не указать иное в css

Comment: За  двое суток 2 абсолютно одинаковых вопроса. Зачем задавать вопрос второй раз, если на него ответили первый раз, а ты еще и ответ принял как верный...???  Если что-то не понятно можно и нужно переспросить. Нормально бы описал в вопросе, что именно не получается какой должен быть конечный результат...

Comment: @Air не серчай я не со зла , просто не разобрался и срочно нужен был ответ , я здесь 3  день всего )

Comment: @KamilSadekov, добро пожаловать...))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
body {
  background-image: 
  url("/Users/kamil/Desktop/ Mebel/изображения /body.jpg"); 
height: 100%;
position:relative; 
}

.top-menu {
  background:#630000;
  box-shadow: 3px 0 7px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  padding: 15px;
}
.top-menu:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.navbar-logo {display: inline-block;}
.menu-main {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: right;
}
.menu-main li {display: inline-block;}
.menu-main a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 61px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-family: 'Arimo', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #EAE2C9;
  transition:.3s linear;
}
.menu-main a:before {
  content: "";
  width: 9px;
  height: 9px;
  background: #EAE2C9;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(6.5px);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .3s linear;
}
.menu-main a:hover:before {opacity: 1;}
@media (max-width: 660px) {
.menu-main {
  float: none;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.top-menu {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0 0 0;
}
.menu-main a {padding: 0 10px;}
.menu-main a:before {transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(-6px);}
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
.menu-main li {display: block;}
}


.container{
  background-color:#EAE2C9;
  border-width:3px;
  border-color:#000000;
  width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  max-width: 1480px;
  min-height:100px;
  overflow: auto;
  height:100%;
  }



  .container{
    height:100%;
  }


h1{
  text-align:center;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0,auto;
}


.logoo{
color:#630000;
font-family: 'Pattaya', sans-serif;
}


/*.information{
  text-align:center;
  font-size: 2vw;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
 <title>Контакты</title>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">

  <meta charset="utf-8"/>

 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Contrail+One" rel="stylesheet">

 <link href="/Users/kamil/Desktop/ Mebel/css/contact.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Users/kamil/Desktop/ Mebel/css/bootstrap.css"/>

   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pattaya" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <!-- меню в разделе ;контакты;-->
 <nav class="top-menu">
  <a class="navbar-logo" href="/Users/kamil/Desktop/ Mebel/index.html"><img src="/Users/kamil/Desktop/ Mebel/изображения /logo.jpg" height="80" width="200"></a>
  <ul class="menu-main">
    <li><a href="">Товары</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Услуги</a></li>
    <li><a href="">О нас</a></li>
    <li><a href="" id="cont">Контакты</a></li>
    <li class="text-center"><a href="8-987-724-1869">tel:8-987-724-186</a></li>
    <li class="text-right"><a href="8-902-100-4887">tel:8-902-100-488</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="container">
  


<div style="width:100%;text-align:center;"><h1>«Студия мебели <span class="logoo">Идеал</span>»</h1></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

А какой заголовок и куда Вы хотите вставить/отцентрировать? Приведите только часть/пример кода, а не весь кусочище вставлять. Не понятно куда и что Вы хотите. Может поможет обычный

`margin:0 auto` с указанием фиксированной ширины.

Также можно отцентрировать используя **позиционирование**

Вот вот вся инфа будет с выключкой по центру

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]